# Building a re-serializable wrapper class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, serialization

I'm working on a utility library for use with a complex API model. We receive JSON-parsed objects from the wire with some kind of guarantee about their structure, as follows:

```js
// Known structure of the message:
interface InputBox {
  top: number;
  height: number;
  left: number;
  width: number;
}
interface InputObj {
  box: InputBox
}

// User code (outside our scope) does something like:
const inputObj: InputObj = JSON.parse(
  '{ "box": { "top": 0, "height": 10, "left": 1, "width": 2, "color": "red" } }'
);
```

My goal is to create some view of the object which:

- Adds some utility functions & properties
- Stringifies to the same/compatible JSON as the input
- Behaves consistently when treated as mutable
- Preserves any unexpected attributes, if possible

For example, user code might look like:

```js
// In-place or new obj constructor would both be fine:
const easyObj = myCoolLibrary(inputObj);

easyObj.box.top = 5;
console.log(easyObj.box.getBottom());  // '15'

JSON.stringify(easyObj);
// -> { "box": { "top": 5, "height": 10, "left": 1, "width": 2, "color": "red" } }
// (Note box.color still present, although missing from the input interface)
```

After reading a little around options, it seems like:

- There could be a nice in-place solution using [Object.setPrototypeOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) to directly overwrite prototypes in the input, but it's quite recent and not sure if polyfilling for older browsers would work.
- Creating new objects (with classes/prototypes) and cloning properties across with [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) could work since the input objects are known to be simple/boring JSON-able `Object`s... Still needs polyfill on IE, but maybe is a bit more standard?

The thing is, even if these methods are viable, I can't see how they might be implemented in a way that keeps TypeScript happy?

For e.g:

```js
class MyCoolBox implements InputBox {
  constructor(box: InputBox) {
    Object.assign(this, box);
  }

  getBottom() {
    return this.top + this.height;
  }
}
// > Class 'MyCoolBox' incorrectly implements interface 'InputBox'.
// (and doesn't recognise presence of .top, .height)

Object.setPrototypeOf(inputObj.box, MyCoolBox);
inputObj.box.getBottom();
// > Property 'getBottom' does not exist on type 'InputBox'
// Doesn't recognise the change of interface.
```

Am I missing some sensible way to do this that TypeScript could understand? It seems a reasonable ask to just decorate a JSON-parsed object (of known interface) with some methods!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it seems like you have a misunderstanding about how `implements` works. The properties are recognized, it's just that you told the compiler your class *implements* those properties, but never *actually* implemented them. Yes, you do the `Object.assign` in the constructor which achieves the desired result at *runtime*, but the compiler does not know that.

Since you obviously do not want to spell out every possible property of the `InputBox` on the class, the solution is to instead use the fact that classes have interfaces of the same name bound to them. Thus, you can make the `MyCoolBox` interface be a *subtype* of the interface you wish to extend (i.e. the `InputBox`):

```js
interface MyCoolBox extends InputBox { }

class MyCoolBox {
  constructor(box: InputBox) {
    Object.assign(this, box);
  }

  getBottom() {
    return this.top + this.height;
  }
}
```

Secondly, you expect `setPrototypeOf` to behave like a type guard of sorts, whereas it is simply defined as:

```js
ObjectConstructor.setPrototypeOf(o: any, proto: object | null): any
```

meaning that by changing the prototype you change nothing about what the compiler knows about the shape of the `box` object: for it, it's still an `InputBox`. There is also a problem that `class`es in JavaScript are *mostly* a syntactic sugar for functions + prototype-based inheritance.

Setting of the `box` prototype to `MyCoolBox` will fail at runtime when you try to call the `getBottom` method because it's *not static*, and you only set the static side of the class this way. What you actually want is to set the *prototype* of `MyCoolBox` - this will set the instance properties:

```js
const myCoolLibrary = <T extends InputObj>(input: T) => {
  Object.setPrototypeOf(input.box, MyCoolBox.prototype); //note the prototype
  return input as T & { box: MyCoolBox };
};

const enchanced = myCoolLibrary(inputObj);
const bottom = enchanced.box.getBottom(); //OK
console.log(bottom); //10
```

Finally, as per the example above, you need to tell the compiler that the output type is of the enhanced type. You can do this with a simple [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (`as T & { box: MyCoolBox }`) like above or by letting the compiler infer the enhanced type for you:

```js
{
  const myCoolLibrary = (input: InputObj) => {
    return {
      ...input,
      box: new MyCoolBox( input.box )
    }
  };

  const enchanced = myCoolLibrary(inputObj);
  const bottom = enchanced.box.getBottom(); //OK
  console.log(bottom); //10
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkwAcCuEBCA9gB6oDewqqEhWAXKmDgLYBGsA3JagBZQgBzHhAZM2nbgBsocEYxbsYXKgHcQAEwg9RCiQF9goSLEQoM2PAHlWAK3LdWJBplwESwA0ejxkaALIAngDChISSRKRQxNBg6gDO5q4R5KieSJIIcQmBIWHJFFRIhGBxEDA4SDQwABSOxM4WbsQAlPZUVNY2UJUAdJlxgmDVWiBxADSodc3KqYZUAlBuEDTM1a0F7TCLODBg1DyjPTRYqADU%204d8gsIzBmnFpajgrp0NL7aoALyoAFIAypYAHI9LAIGBxKDVADkZFQACI6nCGLC4cckagAAwTOFXIQQdEARix8OkskJ2LUmh46IATNiipJCDB0XCtuo4alUlDpoYNkUShBUMxgqFJAAZECsGBggJfVAAHgAKqgojF4okrLYAHzVZ54BiK1qfLVtdqdboQHoQiAABRghBoEACWCgljgusaPTqExyooiIPtjudUGmqAA9GGwA60Fo0FhAw7g9wqFsIDs9nrBZlUMqAGQpOoMX15EipW5cbj8x5QMBIHgIWtQdRy4W5cWS6UwAIe942HmFB6CxzLQjMOU1usNlDqL0kHoLJYrNYccNhywAaUrDzCUB6jIEtQdK1DEaJHl5W4FQpFYQlUplcp7%20o1EE6RpNGxT212pvaqB6AGZmMybtIWjBQCoqDFuEJDVE8np1KgzQgQYVB6BWA5XhO9aNs23ytqKd6dt2mZvjMVZDkeo7jrWOHTrOxDzosRAjqsJ5rpumFxDue6EAew7Hiup4Yh4QA)

Comment: @dingus - my pleasure :) this is far from a complete list of what you can do, though, just a couple of clarifications. An off-note: making a copy of the object with the property set to an instance of your enhanced class seems the most reasonable to me given that you are already using class-based approach. `setPrototypeOf` would be more appropriate if `MyCoolBox` was an object